# SQL - Grant role CREATE USER with option to grant CREATE SESSION

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to grant to a role the CREATE USER privilege, such they can create new users. Moreover, I want to grant them the privilege to grant these new users the CREATE SESSION privilege. 
Is it possible without granting them ALL PRIVILEGES or ADMIN OPTION or something too general?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is '`with admin option` too general?

Answer (score 0):

Query to grant session privilege,

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USER;
```